# Swift idiomatic way to guard both aren't nil

Tags: swift

Lets say I have two variables, both optionals:

```
var a:Int? = 42
var b:Int? = 13
```

I have a condition where it's OK to proceed as long as these are not BOTH currently nil. I thoughtlessly put together something like:

```
guard let _ = a, let _ = b else { return }
```

I was absentmindedly thinking the conditions would be OR'ed, rather than AND'ed. Obviously that was wrong. The question then becomes, is there an idiomatic/preferred way to test that? Or do I just regress to the basics:

```
if a == nil && b == nil { return }
```

**Aside**

If I use the message extensions added by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360374/idiomatic-way-to-test-swift-optionals), then I might happily write something like

```
guard a.notNil || b.notNil else { return }
```

Which is about is close as I can come to "make certain (guard) that a is not nil or b is not nil"

Comment: this isn't an answer, but I think going back to an `if` statement is EXACTLY what you need.

Comment: Just use explicit nil check. If you dont want to unwrap, don't use `let`

Comment: I would probably prefer the explicit `if`. – If both optionals are of the same type, you can do `guard case .Some = a ?? b else { return }`

Comment: ... or `guard  a ?? b != nil else  { return }`

Comment: I keep forgetting about `??`, thanks @MartinR! Also: you should make that into an answer. It's valid and quite concise and readable, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `guard` is an `if`, really, so you can do this the same way. This is clear and uses guard, which seems to be part of the fun. I present OR and AND options so you can pick one.

```
func doItOr(a: Int?, b:Int?) {
    guard (a != nil || b != nil) else { return }
    print("either A and B is not nil");
}

func doItAnd(a: Int?, b:Int?) {
    guard (a != nil && b != nil) else { return }
    print("both A and B are not nil");
}


doItOr(nil, b: nil)
doItOr(nil, b: 5)
doItOr(4, b: 5) // prints

doItAnd(nil, b: nil)
doItAnd(nil, b: 5)
doItAnd(nil, b: nil)
doItAnd(4, b: 5) // prints
```

Answer (score 1):

> it's OK to proceed as long as these are not BOTH currently nil

Your question poses two quite different possible conditions, so I will assume, for purposes of discussion, that you mean this one, namely "not both currently nil". Okay, then: "Not" is `!`. "Both" is `&&`. So, like this:

```
guard !(a == nil && b == nil) else {return}
```

Comment: You're right and this answers the question, but an `if` statement is preferable in all ways, I think. Except for the word `guard` it's easier to read in every way.

Comment: @Yar I don't agree and in any case that isn't what the OP asked (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't need to bind `a` or `b` as non-optionals or discern which of the two is non-nil, I believe the idiomatic approach would still be to use the if statement.

I generally use `guard` to narrow the specificity of my parameters by binding optionals, downcasting, etc.

You don't seem to be interested in doing that here. You just want to check them, so `if` seems to appropriately express that.